# logstash date format, not getting any data

Tags: logstash, kibana, logstash-forwarder

Hi following are my configuration in centos6 logstash server. I am using logstash 1.4.2 and elasticsearch 1.2.1. I am forwarding logs from /var/log/messages and /var/log/secure and there time format is "Sep  1 22:15:34"

## 1. input.conf

```
input {
  lumberjack {
    port => 5000
    type => "logs"
    ssl_certificate => "certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
    ssl_key => "private/logstash-forwarder.key"
  }
}
```

## 2. filter.conf

```
filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {

grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
syslog_pri { }
date {
        locale => "en"  // possibly this didn't work in logstash 1.4.2
        match => ["syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss", "ISO8601"]
        add_field => { "debug" => "timestampMatched"}
        timezone => "UTC"
   }
ruby {   code => "event['@timestamp'] = event['@timestamp'].getlocal"}                                        //I saw somewhere instead of "locale => en " we have to use this  in logstash 1.4.2
mutate { replace => [ "syslog_timestamp", "%{syslog_timestamp} +0545" ] }                               //this probably won't work and give date parsing error
 }
}
```

## 3. output.conf

```
output {
  elasticsearch { host => "logstash_server_ip" }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Below is logstash-forwarder conf in all client server

```
{
  "network": {
    "servers": [ "logstash_server_ip:5000" ],
    "timeout": 15,
    "ssl ca": "certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
  },
  "files": [
    {
      "paths": [
        "/var/log/messages",
        "/var/log/secure"
       ],
      "fields": { "type": "syslog" }
    }
   ]
}
```

Here is the problem. I am forwarding logs from 5 servers with different timezone eg: EDT, NDT, NST, NPT. The logstash_server timezone is in NPT (Nepali time) [UTC + 5:45]

All server giving following

```
2014/09/02 08:09:02.204882 Setting trusted CA from file: certs/logstash-forwarder.crt
2014/09/02 08:09:02.205372 Connecting to logstash_server_ip:5000 (logstash_server_ip)
2014/09/02 08:09:02.205600 Launching harvester on new file: /var/log/secure
2014/09/02 08:09:02.205615 Starting harvester at position 5426763: /var/log/messages
2014/09/02 08:09:02.205742 Current file offset: 5426763
2014/09/02 08:09:02.279715 Starting harvester: /var/log/secure
2014/09/02 08:09:02.279756 Current file offset: 12841221
2014/09/02 08:09:02.638448 Connected to logstash_server_ip
2014/09/02 08:09:09.998098 Registrar received 1024 events
2014/09/02 08:09:15.189079 Registrar received 1024 events
```

which I hope is good but only one with timezone NPT is forwarding the logs and I am able to see it in kibana, all others gave me above logs but I am not able to see it in kibana. I think the problem is in DATE since it is not able to parse the date from different server. Also there is no log showing error in logstash.

How do I solve the problem in this case?

Comment: Is logstash generating any errors to it's log?  If it's having problems parsing a date, I'd expect to see errors in the logstash log.

Comment: No, logstash doesn't show any error however I m not able to see any logs in kibana except one server whose timezone matches the logstash server, when I changed the logstash server timezone to EDT from NPT, then it shows logs from all server why is that??

Answer (score 0):

In logstash-forwarder config change

```
"fields": { "type": "syslog" }
```

to

```
"fields": { "type": "syslog", "syslog_timezone": "Asia/Kathmandu" }
```

And change filter.conf to

```
filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    # Set timezone appropriately
    if [syslog_timezone] in [ "Asia/Kathmandu" ] {
      date {
        match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
        remove_field => [ "syslog_timezone" ]
        timezone => "Asia/Kathmandu"
      }
    } else if [syslog_timezone] in [ "America/Chicago", "US/Central" ] {
      date {
        match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
        remove_field => [ "syslog_timezone" ]
        timezone => "America/Chicago"
      }
    } else if [syslog_timezone] =~ /.+/ {
      date {
        match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
        add_tag => [ "unknown_timezone" ]
        timezone => "Etc/UTC"
      }
    } else {
      date {
        match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
        timezone => "Etc/UTC"
      }
    }
  }
}
```